# I need my JQuery slideshow to change div content on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, html

Hello again my JS saviors! I have another dilema:: I have a div titled "homebanner" that contains text and a background image. My client decided that he wanted the #homebanner to change on reload with 4 images/slides.

So, I did this to change the background::

JS CODE

```
jQuery(function($){
$('#homebanner').css({backgroundColor: "#fff"}); 
var totalCount = 4; 
var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
function setBGImage() { 
var bgimage = 'http://bwpcommunications.com/TESTING/images/homepage/'+num+'.jpg';
$('#homebanner').css(
{
backgroundImage:"url("+bgimage+")",
}); 
} 
setBGImage(); 
});
```

And it works great! So I'm stoked about that. But I can't figure out a way to have specific headline text to correspond with each image. Is this possible? Also, here's a link to the test site http://www.bwpcommunications.com/TESTING/. As you can see, when you refresh the page the image changes but the text does not.

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks,

Shadna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put whatever headline text options you want into an array

```
var hText = ["blue jeans", "red jeans", "ripped jeans", "plaid"];
```

then right after setting the background image, you can use the `num` variable to pick the corresponding text from the array (or if you want it random you can just do the random number generation again).  Then it's just a matter of setting the text on the page.

```
$('#htxt').html(hText[num]);
```

or in plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById('htxt').innerHTML = hText[num];
```

depending how the images are numbered, you might need to do `num - 1` since the array is 0 indexed.

Comment: And I'm back! Your solution works perfectly! I am wondering if there's a way to style those strings of text however. For example: if I wanted to have one word in yellow and/or linked to a url, is there a way to do that in the string?

 var hText = ["", "WE SPEAK ARCHITECTURE", "WE HAVE HIGH SPIRIT(S)", "STRATEGY: BUILT ON HUMAN-CENTERED"];

@flapjacks

Comment: Absolutely! Using that jsfiddle you can just add the html right into the hText array. var hText = ["WE SPEAK <a href=\"urlLink\">ARCHITECTURE</a>"].  You can then just use your css to give it the yellow color. @Shanda